# Particle.io Electron firmware "Error writing firmware...Incorrect platform id"

Tags: particle.io

When flashing an updated application to a new Electron device running 0.6 firmware, I get the following error:

```
Error writing firmware...Incorrect platform id (expected 10, parsed 0), use --force to override
```

I can flash an old application just fine, but it's not accepting any updated or new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Simply need to build for the correct device platform in the WebIDE.  Go to Devices and check that the little star next to your device is selected (gold).